# Use enviroment variables in yarn package.json

Tags: heroku, npm, environment-variables, bitbucket, yarnpkg

I want to pull from a private package hosted on bitbucket. Since SSH is not an option for my deploy setup, I want to access the repo using the Application Password.

So my entry in the package JSON looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@companyName/repository": "git+https://${$BITBUCKET_USER}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org/company name/repository.git",
```

Coding username and password hard into the repo URL works fine but when I perform `yarn install` as above, the environment variables are not replaced by its values.

Is there any way to use environment variables like this?

Comment: Post complete `package.json` and your `Procfile`, this would probably need a workaround

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can write a `preinstall` hook that updates `package.json` with values from the environment. Luckily the order of lifecycle hooks work as prescribed using `yarn`.

```
{
  "name": "njs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "preinstall": "node preinstall.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "@companyName/repository": "git+https://${$BITBUCKET_USER}:${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}@bitbucket.org/companyName/repository.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**preinstall.js** example:

```
const package = require('./package.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const {BITBUCKET_USER = 'test', BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD='test'} = process.env;

package.dependencies["@companyName/repository"] = package.dependencies["@companyName/repository"]
    .replace("${$BITBUCKET_USER}", BITBUCKET_USER)
    .replace("${BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD}", BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD);

fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(package, null, 4));
```

**Bonus:**

How you choose to replace environment variables in `preinstall.js` is left to your good judgment. Yes, you can totally use ES6 template tags.

Comment: Just verified and this works great. Great approach, just that one should not use it locally, else the file will be overwritten in local also

Comment: Works great, except that the username and password will be saved as text in the yarn.lock file. Another solution is to use `.git-credentials`

Comment: @Hooman, I think no-code approaches are better. You should totally write an answer for the `.git-credentials` approach.